# Shapefile to table within python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, table, dbf

I was just curious as to whats the best way within a python script to get the output a dbf file/ table while the input is a shapefile. (if possible which i'm assuming it is)

Is there a way of converting a shape file into a table, or by selecting the attribute table of the shapefile and  just outputting that.

Or am i going to need to create a table and then import the values?

Comment: If you have the path to your shapefile stored as a string variable (say, `path_to_shp`), you can simply do `path_to_dbf = path_to_shp.replace('.shp', '.dbf')` and use the attribute table for that shapefile directly.

Comment: if all you're looking to do is convert the dbf to a different format, Excel will read a dbf (though it won't write one in Excel 2007 and newer). You can read the dbf and write it as csv or any other Excel-compatible format. You can also convert from shapefile to csv with gdal_translate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a very simple implementation using [Table to Table (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000027000000).

```
import arcpy

ws = r'C:\temp'
file = r'C:\temp\poly.shp'

arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(file, ws, "outTable.dbf")
```

For an even more efficient pure python approach, you can copy the shapefile's .dbf file using [shutil](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html):

```
import shutil

file = r'C:\temp\poly.dbf'
outFile = r'C:\temp\poly_copy.dbf'

shutil.copyfile(file, outFile)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! 
I didn't even know there was a tool for that! 
thanks again Aaron! Have a great day!

Comment: .dbf extension is not required for outTable.